# Why Geolocation HTML5 getCurrentPosition() is not working on Google Map?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is the error that I am getting while running  below javascript file

getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See https for more details.

This is my javascript file

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   
<script
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA4HSRrQSje--aI6ImtJF30s5ezaUWxsow&libraries=places"></script>

<script>
function getLocation()
    {
      console.log("In geolocation");
        if (navigator.geolocation)
        {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        }
       else
       {
        print("Browser doesn't support geolocation");
       }

 function showPosition(position)
    {
        console.log("in show position");
        dest_lat=position.coords.latitude;
        dest_long=position.coords.longitude;

        url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+ dest_lat + ',' + dest_long + '&sensor=false';
         $.get(url, function(data)
          {
                  if (data.status == 'OK')
                   {
                      map.setCenter(data.results[0].geometry.location);                
                          console.log("Dragaed lat "+marker.getPosition().lat());
                          console.log("Dragged lng "+marker.getPosition().lng());
                          console.log("Address "+data.results[0].formatted_address);
                   }
              });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="LocateMe" onclick="getLocation();"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The error message is very clear, what don't you understand about it? You can't use those functions on a page that is not served via https.

Comment: Hey! Baoo. I can see the error. I am able to understand it. But I was facing issues in resolving it. Finally, I figured it out. It's just that I am a novice to web programming. Thank's.

Comment: I believe it should work in `localhost` as it is treated as secure. In Google Chrome atleast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put it one a server with `https://`!

If you are using Visual Studio, you can configure to lunch the site with `https://` see: https://dotnetcodr.com/2015/09/18/how-to-enable-ssl-for-a-net-project-in-visual-studio/
Alternativelyyou can test it on jsfiddler, which uses https per default.

Besides that your code has a lot of other errors.

- Brackets don't match
- `map` object is not defined in your example
- varibles are not declared (they are added to the global namespace which can cause some really nasty problems later on and throws an error when you use `"use strict"`)

Here is a working excample on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3gkkvs50/
(stackoverflow doesn't use https for the examples)

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="LocateMe" onclick="getLocation();" />
```

JS:

```
function getLocation() {
  console.log("In geolocation");
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else {
    print("Browser doesn't support geolocation");
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  console.log("in show position");
  var dest_lat = position.coords.latitude;
  var dest_long = position.coords.longitude;

  var url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + dest_lat + ',' + dest_long + '&sensor=false';
  $.get(url, function(data) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  });
}
```

Comment: That's works for me and I got clear picture of issue and solution as well. Thank's Stefan.